# Generic method with multiple optional constraints but only one Generic Parameter (c#)

Tags: c#, generics

Is something like this even possible. I want the case, that it executes, when T is MyClass **or** MyOtherClass.

```
public T Method<T>()
   where T: MyClass, T: MyOtherClass
   { //execution }
```

Comment: Why would that be useful? Does `MyClass` and `MyOtherClass` have something in common?

Comment: That wouldn't be particularly generic, though. And no, it's not possible (not counting explicit runtime checks). You could have a `MethodMyClass` and `MethodMyOtherClass`.

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do? It almost looks like you want to use Discriminated Unions, like those found in TypeScript or F#. You can't do this easily in C# yet, not even C# 10, as DUs were pushed to vNext once again. There may be other ways to get the same functionality though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible but you can use an interface for this.

For example:

```
public interface IMyInterface...

public class MyClass : IMyInterface...

public class MyOtherClass : IMyInterface...

public T Method<T>() where T : IMyInterface...
```

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, that's possible to use some constraints, but not 2 classes as the class type should always be the first one. In the question, he wants 2 classes.

Comment: I noticed that `or` only afterr Jeroen Mosfert pointed it out.